# ACM1602B-FL-YBW turns off after a few seconds

Tags: arduino, display

I'm trying to make a rock, paper, scissor game using an Arduino Uno, three buttons and an ACM1602B-FL-YBW display.

I have problems just doing a simple "Hello World" with this display.

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>

// initialize the library with the numbers of the interface pins
LiquidCrystal lcd(12,11,10,7,6,5,4);

void setup() {
  // set up the LCD's number of columns and rows:
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  // Print a message to the LCD.
  lcd.print("hello, world!");
}

void loop() {
  // set the cursor to column 0, line 1
  // (note: line 1 is the second row, since counting begins with 0):
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  // print the number of seconds since reset:
  lcd.print(millis() / 1000);
}
```

Looking at videos, this code should print "Hello World" in the first row of the display and the number of seconds passed from last Arduino reset, and I should see the counter going on and on every second.

But I see just "Hello World" and a number, and after one second nothing is displayed.

Every time I reset, I see "Hello world" again and the number of seconds passed since the last reset, then it turns off again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the prolem, the contrast was too high to let the display be powered by an USB cable, so I just linked the contrast pin to the GND. No problems after that.